# What's wrong with my xml configuration?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-jms

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd 
                       http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
                       http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
```

When I run this application, it complains saying:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value =
>   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
>   http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core' must have even number of
>   URI's.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is missing your last schema URI that you give within your beans tag, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd". Is it possible that you have another copy of the configuration in which you left out that URI, or haven't deployed the configuration that has that URI?

The exception doesn't match the configuration, so that's why I'm asking if what you've given as the configuration is completely accurate.